# Why does layoutSubviews of a UITableViewCell report label's frame as 0?

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

I created a very simple `UITableViewCell1` with nothing but a label, and I constrained the label to the cell's `contentView` bounds.

In `layoutSubviews()` if I print the label's frame it reports the label's frame as `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, but I can see clearly when I run that the label's frame is not 0.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

```
class SimpleTitleLabelCell: UITableViewCell {

    lazy private(set) var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        self.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.text = "Title"
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor),
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        return titleLabel
    }()

   override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("\(self.titleLabel.frame)") 
        //prints (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    }

}
```

Here is how I instantiate the cell in the `TableViewController`.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    }

     override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
     }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return 1
     }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          return SimpleTitleLabelCell()
      }
}
```

Comment: Does the frame get printed multiple times? And if so, is it always `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`?

Comment: No, only a single time.